# NetBeans + CDNJS

Tags: netbeans

Recently I noticed that NetBeans 8.2 is not allowing my to make use of the CDNJS functionality.  After updating to NetBeans 11 (VC 2), I see that the issue is still there.  Is this something in my configuration alone or are other folks experiencing this same issue?  Any direction in how to solve this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2183?jql=text%20~%20%22CDNJS%22

There is a solution.  In short find the netbeans.conf file in [Netbeans Install Dir]\etc

Then find the section netbeans_default_options and add:

-J-Dnetbeans.cdnjs.searchurl=https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries?fields=description,homepage,assets&search=

at the end, make sure it is before the double quote and leave a space after the last entry.

This worked for me on Netbeans 10, 9 and 8.2

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Tried it in both v8.2 and the current latest v11-vc4, and seems to be working fine in both.  The only variation I added was that I placed the URL between single-quotes.  Lots of thanks!